# Can I use a URL launcher to pick a location on map?

Tags: flutter, google-maps-api-3, api-key, location-provider, url-launcher

I am wondering to know if I rather to not integrate google or other maps into my application using API keys, is there a way to place a button in the app that opens the devices default map and user can search and find a desired place, then the app closes the map and picks the location [long,lat]/address for it's internal usage?

Is it possible to have a location/address picker without using APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pick lat/long without Google Maps API you can use `flutter_map` plugin that developed by fleaflet. You can generate map on your app screen with Google maps view or Open street view. And also you can pick lat/long when touching the map.

Here is the documentation
https://docs.fleaflet.dev